# After lerna can support monorepo, what are the advantages of Rush?

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, mono, lerna

I have checked a lot of data. Perhaps due to the timeliness, the advantage of Rush is to support pnpm.

But in fact, lerna can also support pnpm: https://lerna.js.org/docs/recipes/using-pnpm-with-lerna

Because lerna was released earlier, it has a better ecology and mature community than rush.

What are the advantages of Rush in this situation?

Background:

I am selecting the technology for my monorepo.

Comment: Rush is backed by Microsoft, and is engineered with much larger monorepos in mind.

Comment: Please fix the URL it has a 404

Answer (score 0):

Briefly write down the research and practice results during this period.

**Similarity:** both can perform dependency management and version management in monorepo.

**Differences:** relatively speaking, Rush is more strict and standardized in project management, and has more content to configure. Lerna is backed by nx. At present, functions such as graph dependency analysis are not available to Rush.

- **Ecological environment:** Compared with rush, lerna is more mature and the community is more active.
- **Package management tools:** both npm/yarn/pnpm support